# jQuery Ajax function says "failure" but still sends message

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a problem here which I feel I'm missing something but I can't put my finger on it.

I have the following:

```
function success(){
    alert("success");   
}
function failure(){
    alert("failure");   
}

function sendData(){
    var userName = $("#contact-name-data").val();
    var userPhone = $("#contact-phone-data").val();
    var userEmail = $("#contact-email-data").val();
    var userQuery = $("#contact-enquiry-data option:selected").text();

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "http://my.domain-blahblah.com.au/scripts/touchscreen_email.cfm?name="+encodeURIComponent(userName)+"&phone="+encodeURIComponent(userPhone)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(userEmail)+"&query="+encodeURIComponent(userQuery), success: success, error: failure});

}
```

which fires off to a very simple CFMAIL command pulling the values from the respective parameters in the URL when called...

Problem is that it tells me that it's failed by the "failure" pop-up every time I call the function... and yet still fires off the email correctly. The ColdFusion is sound and perfect. So I'm thinking my Ajax must be screwed somewhere...

Any idea what I might be missing?

the server-side code:

```
    <cftry>
<cfmail from="touchscreen@my.domain-blahblah.com.au" to="eliseo.dannunzio@my.domain-blahblah.com.au" subject="Touchscreen Data" type="html" spoolenable="yes">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: 'Calibri';
                font-size: 12pt;
            }

            h3 {
                margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   
            }

            span {
                font-weight: bold;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Touchscreen Data</h3>
        <p>
            <span>Name: </span>#url.name#<br />
            <span>Phone: </span>#url.phone#<br />
            <span>E-Mail: </span>#url.email#<br />
            <span>Request: </span>#url.query#<br />
            <span>Timestamp: </span>#DateFormat(Now(), "dd mmm yyyy")# #TimeFormat(Now(), "hh:mm tt")#<br />
        </p>
    </body>
</cfmail>
<cfcatch type="any">
    #cfcatch.Message# - #cfcatch.Detail#
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
Done
```

Comment: What HTTP status code do you get for your ajax request?

Comment: According to the function, once I parse out the request object... it's returning a status of 0 and a statusText of "error"...

Comment: Use something like firebug or development tools to see the status code.

Answer (score 1):

Won't it be better to do the ajax request like this?

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://my.domain-blahblah.com.au/scripts/touchscreen_email.cfm",
  type: "get",
  date: { name : encodeURIComponent(userName), phone : encodeURIComponent(userPhone), email : encodeURIComponent(userEmail), query : encodeURIComponent(userQuery)},
  success: success,
  error: failure
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have u tried doing this....i think this is the right way to call an ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://my.domain-blahblah.com.au/scripts/touchscreen_email.cfm",
  data:{name:encodeURIComponent(userName),phone:encodeURIComponent(userPhone),email:encodeURIComponent(userEmail),query:encodeURIComponent(userQuery)}, 
  type:'GET',
  success: function(msg){ //do something here }, 
  error: failure
 });
```

Comment: Just tried that, with a few minor fixes to correct the code... (missing commas, quotes, etc) and it's still reporting a failure and yet still allowing to send it through...

No idea what's going on... I mean how hard can an Ajax call be, right?

Comment: ok.. i don't think ajax is required here .if  i am not worng......
try using this.. 
`window.location='http://my.domain-blahblah.com.au/scripts/touchscreen_email.cfm?name="+encodeURIComponent(userName)+"&phone="+encodeURIComponent(userPhone)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(userEmail)+"&query="+encodeURIComponent(userQuery)';`

Comment: @bipen, in this case it's essential as I'm running the code as part of an app I'm building and am not wanting to move away from the current page... The box that this app will be sitting on will not have access to a mail server except remotely. As a result the Ajax is necessary to send the request to9 the remote server performing the mail out via CFMAIL.

Comment: @bipen and DarkRanger just tried that version and it's still coming back with "failure"...

This is what's really puzzling me... I'm sending the request... the request is definitel going through because I'm getting the email... but the response from the $.ajax call isn't right... 

Should we keep trying to resolve it or should I just try to set up the CFCATCH in the server side code to shoot back any issues experienced and not worry about reporting them on the client end?